# programming for Xbee meshing

Tags: xbee, svd-xbee

i have one query actually i have 3 `xbees series2`.
i want `xbee 1 (sensor+xbee(end device))` and  `xbee 2` as coordinator,where `XBee2` will be attched to MCU. 
now i have `xbee 3` which again `((sensor+xbee(end device))`.
now i want to make `xbee3` also to communicate with `coordinator(Xbee2)`.
now i have kept the same pan ID of `Xbee1` and `xbee3` as like `Xbee2`.
and again i have set `xbee1` and `xbee3` destination address for the `Xbee 2` .

now my question are

1. how do i program the MCU using eclipse environment for receiving both `Xbee1` and `Xbee3` data?
2. and i want to communicate all `Xbees` with UART communication means i want to read data using pin 2 and 3 of `Xbee`..is it possible??

can anyone provide me the code for developing this procedure???

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario.  Run the coordinator in API mode and the end devices (you may want to start with those nodes as routers, and figure out the "sleeping end device" details once everything else is working) in AT mode.

The "AT mode" devices with `DH` and `DL` set to 0 will just pass serial data to the coordinator, and the MCU can parse the API frames to determine which device sent the data.  The MCU can also address requests to the other devices -- either Remote AT Commands or data to send out the serial port.

Write code for the MCU however you normally would.  There's a [portable ANSI C library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) available if that's your language of choice.  It can parse the API frames for you and simplify communications on the network.